# Whats the difference between a Base64 and a cdn that comes from the image providers servers?

Tags: base64, cdn

I was using an image source that gave too options Base64 and image served from their CDN what's the difference? Is there any advantages or disadvantages?

```
<img class="icon icons8-Bebo" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADAAAAAwCAYAAABXAvmHAAA" width="48" height="48">


<img src="https://maxcdn.icons8.com/Color/PNG/24/Social_Networks/bebo-24.png" title="Bebo" width="24">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in the source of the image data:

- For **base64**, data is inside HTML tag
- For **CDN:**, image is hosted on our CDN

Of these two, I'd choose base64. It's more flexible: you can resize and recolor the icons (for CDN you have too choose from the predefined sizes).